# HTML links working everywhere but my navbar

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on creating a sample reports and an about page for a business website. It uses bootstrap 3 but I created a custom navbar for aesthetic's sake, but now my links will not work inside the navbar as they do everywhere else. I've tried switching from li with anchor tags to just anchor tags and I have tried the jquery filter option as well, but neither worked. here's my code:

```
<div class="row coloroverlay">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10"></div>
                <div class="nav-toggle col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                      <div class="nav-toggle-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
                <nav class="nav nav-overlay">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://visbanking.com" class="external">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://visbanking.com/v4/about.html" class="external">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="external">Sample Reports</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
              </div>
```

and javascript:

```
(function() {

    var hamburger = {
      navToggle: document.querySelector('.nav-toggle'),
      nav: document.querySelector('nav'),
    
      doToggle: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.navToggle.classList.toggle('expanded');
        this.nav.classList.toggle('expanded');
      }
    };
    
    hamburger.navToggle.addEventListener('click', function(e) { hamburger.doToggle(e); });
    hamburger.nav.addEventListener('click', function(e) { hamburger.doToggle(e); });
    
    }());

    $(document).singlePageNav({filter: ':not(.external)'});
```

If you guys could help that would be great

Comment: Show this code use Code Snippet

Comment: when you inspect element are you able to get the element? It might be a z-index issue or a div overlapping the navbar.

Comment: It's not a z-index issue, I've checked that already. and I tried to get it set up as a code snippet but it didn't toggle right